# Microsoft app ID under the bot service on Azure

Tags: botframework

While creating Microsoft app ID under the bot service on Azure, encountering message as "Insufficient privileges to perform this operation. Please ask your administrator to allow users to register applications".
I am using free trial subscription of Azure. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi SIVA! It sounds like there might be an issue with your azure subscription. Can you please edit your question and post screenshots of the message you're encountering?

Comment: I came across similar problem before, but I'm not using a free trial though. It turned out the problem I have is that I registered using my company email which doesn't authorize me to modify Microsoft app ID. Switching to a personal email for the Azure account may solve the problem. I'm not sure whether similar rule applies to free trial subscription though. May it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You lack permissions to create application registrations in your company's tenant.
[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#why-do-i-get-an-authorizationrequestdenied-exception-when-creating-a-bot) has information on what this means.
To summarize so you don't have to read that whole page:
In the Azure Portal, go to your Active Directory tenant.
Click on 'Users and Groups'
Select the 'User Settings' blade.
Under 'App Registrations' see if the setting 'Users can register applications' is set to 'Yes' or 'No'. 
It is probably set to 'No'
[image]
Your company's Active Directory admin will need to change this setting to 'Yes' in order for you to register your bot app under your company's tenant. 
The other option is to have you AD admin register to bot for you and provide to AppId and App Password that is generated.